# click event listener stops default

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

Is there any way of altering which order events fire in with relation to their parent default event?  I am thinking specifically of the 'click' event which seems to fire differently between Firefox and Internet Explorer.

We have an `<a>` tag which closes a modal window (#modal1):

```html
<a href="#" id="closeElement">close</a>
```

So as to prevent a new history entry when it is closed we have the following javascript to trigger on the click event.

```js
closeElement.addEventListener("click", function(){  history.back(); });
```

Problem is under IE this line seems to prevent the default 'click' event from happening.  In this case the location.hash gets changed as expected but the modal window still remains on screen, it looks like the default behavior has been interrupted and not executed properly.   However it works fine under Firefox.

It seems as if Firefox executes the default click event before the .addEventListener("click") event while IE does the opposite and runs the custom click event before the default.

Any suggestions how to control this to make the code work under both Firefox and IE.

Edit:
Perhaps one workaround might be to move the history.back() inside the hashChange event.  Only problem there is how to identify from within that hashChange event what triggered it?  In this case was the hashChange triggered by the button link of a modal window.

Comment: Simplest solution to the underlying problem would be omitting the unnecessary call to `href='#'`.

Comment: Unfortunately that will not work.  The href='#' is necessary to stop the page reloading as happens if href=""

Comment: Why not use a button or div for the close element instead of a link?

Comment: Well the idea is so that it will work even if Javascript is not enabled.  Just that without Javascript some of the nicer history fixes will not work.

Comment: Is it a dialog that wouldn't open if you didn't have Javascript enabled in the first place?

Comment: And, anyway, if you really think you need it (you really shouldn't...), [remove the attribute with Javascript](https://jsfiddle.net/x9uurLe5/2/).